# Laravel google charts issue

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have an issue that my google chart doesnt work. I am using laravel so a blade template and the javascript implementation of the chart.
Here is my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chartData = [ @json($chart) ];

    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTrendlines);

    function drawTrendlines() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'X');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
        data.addRows([
            chartData
        ]);

        var options = {
            hAxis: {
            title: 'Date'
            },
            vAxis: {
            title: 'Value'
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

And this is console log of my chartData array:

```
[
   Array(
      5)
   ]   0:   Array(5)


0:   (2)   [
      "2020-03-03",
      70
   ]   1:   (2)   [
      "2020-03-03",
      71
   ]   2:   (2)   [
      "2020-03-03",
      71
   ]   3:   (2)   [
      "2020-03-03",
      70
   ]   4:   (2)   [
      "2020-03-03",
      70
   ]   "length":   5

__proto__:   Array(0)

length:   1

__proto__:   Array(0)
```

Error i get: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Row 0 given with size different than 2 (the number of columns in the table).

It seems like i am missing the 'new Date(*SOMEDATE*)' in the array and that might be the issue but how can i wrap my data with that? Any help making this work would be awesome.

Comment: Please try `var chartData = @json($chart);` (Remove extra `[]`)

Comment: Also here `data.addRows([chartData]);` You add yet another array level. Try `data.addRows(chartData);`